# is it possible to use native R code or other R package functions with sparklyr?

Tags: r, sparkr, sparklyr

I've gotten to the point where I can follow along with the example [here](http://spark.rstudio.com/extensions.html) (with only the slight modification of adding `config=list()` to the input arguments).

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config=list())
library(dplyr)
flights_tbl <- copy_to(sc, nycflights13::flights, "flights")
flights_tbl %>% filter(dep_delay == 2)

Source:   query [?? x 16]
Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr local=FALSE

    year month   day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay carrier  tailnum     flight origin  dest air_time distance  hour minute
   <int> <int> <int>    <int>     <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>   <chr>    <chr>      <int>  <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   2013     1     1      517         2      830        11    "UA" "N14228"       1545  "EWR" "IAH"      227     1400     5     17
2   2013     1     1      542         2      923        33    "AA" "N619AA"       1141  "JFK" "MIA"      160     1089     5     42
3   2013     1     1      702         2     1058        44    "B6" "N779JB"        671  "JFK" "LAX"      381     2475     7      2
4   2013     1     1      715         2      911        21    "UA" "N841UA"        544  "EWR" "ORD"      156      719     7     15
5   2013     1     1      752         2     1025        -4    "UA" "N511UA"        477  "LGA" "DEN"      249     1620     7     52
6   2013     1     1      917         2     1206        -5    "B6" "N568JB"         41  "JFK" "MCO"      145      944     9     17
7   2013     1     1      932         2     1219        -6    "VX" "N641VA"        251  "JFK" "LAS"      324     2248     9     32
8   2013     1     1     1028         2     1350        11    "UA" "N76508"       1004  "LGA" "IAH"      237     1416    10     28
9   2013     1     1     1042         2     1325        -1    "B6" "N529JB"         31  "JFK" "MCO"      142      944    10     42
10  2013     1     1     1231         2     1523        -6    "UA" "N402UA"        428  "EWR" "FLL"      156     1065    12     31
# ... with more rows
```

However, when I try to use other R functions like one might do with `dplyr` things go awry:

```
flights_tbl %>% filter(dep_delay == 2 & grepl("A$", tailnum)) 
Source:   query [?? x 16]
Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr local=FALSE

Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: undefined function GREPL; line 4 pos 41
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2$$anonfun$1.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:69)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2$$anonfun$1.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:69)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry$$anonfun$lookupFunction$2.apply(hiveUDFs.scala:64)
at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveFunctionRegistry.lookupFunction(hiveUDFs.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$24.apply(Analyzer.scala:574)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveFunctions$$anonfun$apply$12$$anonfun$applyOrElse$5$$anonfun$applyOrElse$24.apply(Analyzer.
```

Obviously `grepl` is not supported. My question is: is there a way to use base R or R package functions? If not is it coming? It seems that work along these lines is progressing with `dapply` and `gapply` in `SparkR` v2, but it would be great if it worked with `sparklyr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just saw [this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/81) for sparklyr. Short answer is "not yet". Looking forward to future versions where this functionality is added.

Comment: "not yet" has changed to "yes it is possible" using `spark_apply`. Any old function can't be used inside `mutate` however since that gets turned into a (Spark) SQL query.

Comment: incidentally, any defined Hive UDF *can* be used inside `mutate`/`summarize`. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF